# Object property values lost on server side when object passed via google.script.run

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

### Preface

I am posting this to warn others of a potential bug in google.script.run, to present a possible work-around, and to solicit further community insights into what might be going on.

### The Problem

I am passing a large data object to a server-side function invoked via google.script.run. Here is it what it looks like on the client-side before the call to Google.script.run (obtained by JSON.stringify'ing and outputting through an alert box):

> {"roundStartTime":"12:00:00","roundFinishTime":"12:45:23","holeData":{"1":{"strokes":1,"finishTime":"12:02:00"},"2":{"strokes":6,"finishTime":"12:04:00"},"3":{"strokes":7,"finishTime":"12:06:00"},"4":{"strokes":8,"finishTime":"12:08:00"},"5":{"strokes":9,"finishTime":"12:10:00"},"6":{"strokes":10,"finishTime":"12:12:00"},"7":{"strokes":11,"finishTime":"12:14:00"},"8":{"strokes":12,"finishTime":"12:16:00"},"9":{"strokes":13,"finishTime":"12:18:00"},"10":{"strokes":1,"finishTime":"12:30:00"},"11":{"strokes":11,"finishTime":"12:33:00"},"12":{"strokes":8,"finishTime":"12:35:00"},"13":{"strokes":3,"finishTime":"12:37:00"},"14":{"strokes":7,"finishTime":"12:39:00"},"15":{"strokes":10,"finishTime":"12:40:00"},"16":{"strokes":11,"finishTime":"12:42:00"},"17":{"strokes":13,"finishTime":"12:45:00"},"18":{"strokes":6}}}`

And here's the same object as it is received on the server-side (obtained by JSON.stringify'ing and outputting through Google's Logger.log function):

> {"roundStartTime":"12:00:00","holeData":{"11":{"strokes":11,"finishTime":"12:33:00"},"12":{"strokes":8,"finishTime":"12:35:00"},"13":{"strokes":3,"finishTime":"12:37:00"},"14":{"strokes":7,"finishTime":"12:39:00"},"15":{"strokes":10,"finishTime":"12:40:00"},"16":{"strokes":11,"finishTime":"12:42:00"},"17":{"strokes":13,"finishTime":"12:45:00"},"18":{"strokes":6,"finishTime":null},"1":{"strokes":1,"finishTime":"12:02:00"},"2":{"strokes":6,"finishTime":"12:04:00"},"3":{"strokes":7,"finishTime":"12:06:00"},"4":{"strokes":8,"finishTime":"12:08:00"},"5":{"strokes":9,"finishTime":"12:10:00"},"6":{"strokes":10,"finishTime":"12:12:00"},"7":{"strokes":11,"finishTime":"12:14:00"},"8":{"strokes":12,"finishTime":"12:16:00"},"9":{"strokes":13,"finishTime":"12:18:00"},"10":{"strokes":1,"finishTime":"12:30:00"}}."roundFinishTime":"12:45:23"}

As you can see, the object appears to be identical, except that the properties of "holeData" appear in a different order on the server-side. *The problem is **NOT** that object properties are ordered differently, however; it is that I simply can't access properties on the server side.* Please read on for more details.

On the server side, I can confirm that the holeData property has the following (sub)properties by JSON.stringify'ing a call to Object.keys(data.holeData):

> ["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]

However, When I then attempt to access the "strokes" (sub)property of any one of these objects, e.g.:

data.holeData["1"].strokes --or-- data.holeData["1"]["strokes"], 
 I get an error:

> Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "strokes" from undefined.

So something unexpected happened to the object when it was transferred from the client to the server side.

Note: I have carefully read the [***rules for legal parameters to google.script.run functions***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run), and my object does not appear to violate any of them. It's composed solely of string and integer data.

### The Solution

I have fixed the issue by applying JSON.stringify() to the object on the client side, and then JSON.parse() on the server-side. When I serialize/deserialize in this way, I am able to access all object properties on the server-side.

Any idea what is happening with this object? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: I don't think that's a bug. It's just that javascript doesn't care about the order of the key of an object. `Object.keys` is not guaranteed to return the same order on one side, never mind an object that being transfered from one side to the other and being reconstructed from scratch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Hi ibrahim, The ordering doesn't matter. What matters is whether I can access object properties. The fact remains that on the client side I can, but on the server side I can't, even though the object has the same properties on both sides. Can you explain this?

Comment: What kind of project are you using? Is this occurring on a dialog, sidebar or web app? I'm using a standalone project for an add-on that includes an installable trigger and a sidebar. The sidebar works fine when running with "test as add-on" but not when running it  as a library in a bound to spreadsheet project. Your solution doesn't work for me (yet?).