# Why are Session and PropertiesService undefined when using react-google-apps-script

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I am using [react-google-apps-script](https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script) to implement a Google Apps Script UI for a spreadsheet.

I have code in my server implementation as

```
const getActiveUserEmail = () => {
  return Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
};
```

It is referenced from the client via:

```
import { getActiveUserEmail } from '../../../server';
const email = getActiveUserEmail();
```

After I deploy to a spreadsheet and run it, I get 'Session' undefined when the code is hit.  I also get 'PropertiesService undefined' if that code is hit.

I'm able to use HtmlService, SpreadsheetApp, and UrlFetch apis without issue.

My appscript.json file contains

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Why are these undefined and how can I force them to be defined?

Update: Enushi has provided a [working code example](https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script/commit/a3239267397fc9187fa713b688a0f7520e188b89).

Comment: Is this a bound script or standalone? Have you enabled the services in script editor?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Better code example provided

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that ...

```
const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
const props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
```

are in the in client-side code (someway they are passed to `HtmlService.htmlOutput`) rather in server-side code.

The above methods might be used with `Html.htmlTemplate` but should be included inside scriptlets to be executed as server-side code.

Related

- [Server side object lost when passed to client side code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50595103/1595451)
- [Reference : TypeError: Cannot read property [property name here] from undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74109026/1595451)

References

- http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html
- http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: This was in fact the problem.  The fact I was importing from server should have been a red flag but the autocomplete added it without me looking at my imports.  The actual fix is to utilize the serverFunctions shim provided by the build system.  e.g. `serverFunctions.getActiveUserEmail().then((response) => console.log(response))` as provided in [this example](https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script/commit/d25c94d89909ad6a223b4f4ac7f88a9d69a6e427)

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution - Don't directly access server side code from the client but use a shim!